# How can I get Stocktwits access_token in Rails app?

Tags: ruby, access-token, stocktwits

I need help with problem. I have website integrated with Stocktwits using omniauth-stocktwits gem. I want to use Stocktwits API to fetch commentary stream. So, I need access_token!

After user authorizes my App at StockTwits I see that I get redirect to my /callback URL with "code" parameter. As I can see in omniauth code this "code" field dont' used for anything. So I decided to try to get access_token how it recommended in api documentation:

```
curl -X POST https://api.stocktwits.com/api/2/oauth/token -d 'client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID&client_secret=MY_SECRET&code=CODE_FROM_REDIRECT_PARAMS&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=http://my.site.url'
```

I was trying many times. With gurl, with HTTParty (my site written in Ruby) - one result:

```
"errors"=>["code doesn't exist or has expired"]}
```

or
    {"response":{"status":403},"errors":[{"message":"Permission denied"}]}

I really sure that all scopes was used and I authorizesa app to read streams, so what permissions are denied I have no idea...

I dont' know how code can be expired if I just get it :(

Where is error? How can I get access_token? Please, any help will be good :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct flow and the right end-point to get the access token once you have the code. Here's our authentication flow: http://stocktwits.com/developers/docs/authentication

I'm not sure why you're getting an invalid code, could you try getting the user's code without the omniauth gem? Or try teaching out to the omniauth-stocktwits gem author: https://github.com/jesseyoungmann/omniauth-stocktwits

Comment: Hi! Thank you for help! If I trying to make all steps just using browser all work normally. So, I'll try to contact gem author. I have other question, can you please take a look and help if you have any ideas? Question is:

Comment: I'm using next scopes when requesting access_token: :scope => "read,watch_lists,publish_messages,publish_watch_lists,direct_messages,follow_users,follow_stocks" but then I want to fetch commentary stream I'm getting "permission denied" How can I debug this problem? I understand that's strange ))

Comment: Hi, you can try contacting the omniauth-stocktwits gem author, Jesse, at: jyoungmann@estimize.com - I'm sure he'll be happy to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

In case this comes up again, for future questions: https://github.com/jesseyoungmann/omniauth-stocktwits/issues/1#issuecomment-11139157